# C++ Line break entered as input automatically if you give a cin an unexpected input inside loop

Tags: c++, input, while-loop, cin

I think I'm having issues with the buffer of the input stream. Whenever I input a very large number (10 or more characters) or a letter for the number1 or number 2 variable the console freaks out and seems to automatically fill every input with a line break while looping forever.

I tried using std::cin.clear(); to stop it from automatically inputting a line break but that didn't work.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    while (1) {
        std::string operatorChoice;
        long int number1, number2;
        number1 = 0;
        number2 = 0;
        std::cout << "<add>, <subtract>, <divide>, <multiply>, or <exit> ";
        std::cin >> operatorChoice;
        if (operatorChoice == "exit") {
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "Number 1: ";
        std::cin >> number1;
        std::cout << "Number 2: ";
        std::cin >> number2;
        if (operatorChoice == "add") {
            std::cout << number1 << " + " << number2 << " = " << number1 + number2 << "\n";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
 add    
 1     
 e
```

Output:

```
1 + 0 = 0    

<add>, <subtract>, <divide>, <multiply>, or <exit> Number 1: Number 2: (this part just repeats forever)
```

I'm hoping there's a way to make the second iteration over the loop act identical to the first and not start inputting line breaks.

Comment: `cin >> value` can fail if `value` is a numeric type.  Once the stream is in a failed state, it takes some code to get out of that state.  `cin.clear()` for example.  When mixing types (strings, characters and numeric types) often it is easier to read everything as a string and do parsing/error checking after the fact

Comment: @Chad it is also needed to flush the input, for instance using _getline_ as I do in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the input given to `std::cin` cannot be converted to the type of the variable it will write, it enters an error state, which can be queried with `cin.fail()` (or synonyms such as `!cin`). If it returns `true` (meaning that the `failbit` of the stream is set), then it means that the conversion failed. While in this fail state, cin will refuse to read any data until the `failbit` is cleared.

In the lines where you read the numbers from the user, you should use a loop that checks the fail state of the stream, if it returns `false`, then continue normal execution, otherwise, call `std::cin.clear()` to clear the `failbit` so `cin`can continue reading as usual.

Keep in mind that the faulty input will still be in the stream (i.e. the 'e' you entered will still be there, so if that input is read again as a int, it will fail again), so call `std::cin.ignore(<A big number like 256>,'\n')` to skip over the bad/faulty input, while prompting the user for correct input (The number passed to ignore is the number of characters it should skip). The '\n' argument means all the characters in the stream are ignored until the next line, without it the user would have to enter the 256 characters.

Comment: the value are given line per line so a _getline_ flush the input

Comment: Using `getline()` to clear or flush the input is less efficient than calling `ignore()`, because you need to create a string to place the contents of the line, and `getline()` will still need to copy the contents of that line to the string, while `ignore()` will just skip that input.

Comment: The ignore causes the program to seemingly freeze. No output occurs.

Comment: Can you show or give a link to the code that freezes with `ignore`?

Comment: I did some digging and found the problem, the cin.ignore() function will ignore all input until the end of the file. I have swapped it out for cin.ignore(256,'\n') so it only ignores until the end of the line. I have marked your answer correct.

Comment: @MaxStrange It shouldn't; the default for the first argument is 1